# Strange FileSystemWatcher behavior

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to monitor writes to a .less file with this code:

```vb
        Using watcher As FileSystemWatcher = New FileSystemWatcher()
            watcher.Path = my-path
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
            watcher.Filter = "*.less"
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = True

            AddHandler watcher.Changed, AddressOf OnChanged
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit the sample.")

            While Console.ReadLine() <> "q"
            End While
        End Using


    Private Sub OnChanged(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As FileSystemEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}")
    End Sub
```

When I save this file (in Visual Studio), nothing happens. But if I filter on *.css instead, and compile the less file to css, I do get the OnChanged event.

Weirder still, if I set the filter to `*.*` and save the file, I get this sequence of messages:

```
File: my-path\czscisu.u3c~ Changed
File: my-path Changed
File: my-path Changed
File: my-path Changed
File: my-path Changed
```

The less file is updating (the timestamp changes, as seen in Explorer), but I never get the event, but I get an event for a random temp file and then four events for the path itself. What's going on here?

Possibly related is that I'm using WebCompiler, which may ALSO be watching less files, but I don't see why that should be a problem.
File: my-path Changed

Comment: That's entirely normal, many existing Q+A about it.  You see the compiler writing to a temporary file.  To rename it when nothing went wrong, preserving the last-known-good file if it did go wrong.  So you need the Renamed event.

Comment: I tried this but I don't get a Renamed event either.

Comment: It turns out that NotifyFilters causes the FSW not to send Renamed. When I changed this, the events work.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the file isn't actually changing, but rather, the file is *deleted* and then a new file with the same name is *created*. Attach event handlers to the [Created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.created?view=netframework-4.8) and [Deleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.deleted?view=netframework-4.8) events and see if those trigger.

Comment: I tried this but I don't get those events either. If I save the file in Notepad++, I do get a Changed event. So it seems like Visual Studio or some extension is doing something to interfere, but I can't see how it would bypass an existing FSW like this.